# Newton's Method for a step size to move in the direction of the gradient

Tags: calculus, gradient-descent, hessian-matrix

I am reading [this](https://blog.paperspace.com/intro-to-optimization-momentum-rmsprop-adam/) article that talks about Newton's method that can give us an ideal step size to move in the direction of the gradient.

I do not understand what $\epsilon$ is in the following part of the article:
[image]

I am confused on what $g$ is and what this math expression represents. 
Can someone help me to understand it?

Thank you!

Comment: You may also be interested in Steffensen's method, another Newton variant that has shrinking step size as we approach the root.

Comment: If you approximate the cost near $x$ by  $f(x+h) \approx \langle g, h \rangle >+ { 1\over 2} \langle h, H h \rangle$ ($g$ is the gradient of $f$, $H$ is the Hessian) and you consider a step in the direction $-g$ then the step size that extremises the approximate cost is given by the above formula. (That is, consider the approximation with parameter $h=-\lambda g$.)